# How do I specify default list values for bash variables?

Tags: arrays, bash

I understand the syntax:

```
foo=${bar:-mydefault}
```

which sets `foo` to `$bar` if it exists, and `mydefault` if not. This works for simple, scalar values. But I can't figure out how to set a default value for a list. I tried things like:

```
foo=${bar[@]:-(my de fault)}
```

but that does not work. It's the default value that trips me up, it does assign `${bar[@]}` as a list if it exists. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as an array *value* in `bash`. `foo=(...)` is a special form of an assignment, rather than a special RHS of a regular assignment. The closest you can come to what you want is to first try to make a copy of `bar`, *then* check if that actually defined `foo`. (If `bar` was empty, `foo` hasn't actually been defined yet, although the array attribute on the *name* `foo` will have been set.)

```
foo=( "${bar[@]}" )
if ! [[ -v foo  ]]; then
    foo=(my de fault)
fi
```

---

Note that even `foo=( "${bar[@]}" )` doesn't make an exact copy of `bar`; the exact indices are not preserved.

```
$ bar=([0]=zero [9]=nine)
$ foo=( "${bar[@]}" )
$ declare -p foo bar
declare -a foo=([0]="zero" [1]="nine")
declare -a bar=([0]="zero" [9]="nine")
```

To preserve the indices as well, you'll need to iterate over them in `bar` directly:

```
$ foo=()
$ for i in "${!bar[@]}"; do foo[i]=${bar[i]}; done
```

Comment: There must be a reason I don't like bash. Ahh. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
foo=(${bar[@]:-my de fault})
```

Remove the parenthesis from `my de fault` and then convert it back into an array.

Comment: That doesn't preserve the contents of `bar` if they themselves contain whitespace or patterns that could be expand, since it's not quoted. If you *do* quote it, then `my de fault` will be treated as a single string to assign to `foo[0]`, not three separate array elements. Try this with `bar=("a b" c)`.